# DateTimePicker control does not show AM/PM

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datetimepicker, datetime-format

I'm having a problem with a DateTimePicker control using a custom format which includes the the two-letter A.M./P.M. abbreviation.

Using an "en-US" CultureInfo DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern results in
"h:mm tt".

But setting this as custom format in a DateTimePicker with the following code:

```
Dim curCul As CultureInfo = New CultureInfo("en-US")
dtpTime.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
dtpTime.CustomFormat = curCul.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern
```

results in only the hour and the minutes being displayed.
I however also need the AM/PM part.

Examples:

11:04 AM is displayed as 11:04

2:00 PM is displayed as  2:00

Additional remark:
I noticed that the DateTimePicker keeps track of the correct time.
If I increase the time (I'm using ShowUpDown = true for this DateTimePicker control) and increase the hour by 12 and save the changes into the database, the AM/PM has changed.
So it seems "only" to be an issue about displaying the AM/PM part.

Thanks for any help.
Frank

Answer (score 13):

Try this

```
dtpTime.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
dtpTime.CustomFormat = "hh:mm tt"
```

Comment: Doesn't work and I do not know why it should work... If I check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.customformat.aspx there is no mention of "aa" so it is simple interpreted as text and display "aa"

Comment: Yes I know, the ShortTimePattern for "en-US" culture is "h:mm tt", as written above.     The problem is the tt which represents AM/PM is not displayed. You can try for yourself...

Comment: Can you please add your code? That would be great, thanks :-)

Comment: @FrankE, same thing, I have just placed the datetime on the form, set the format to custom and in the custom format I have given h:mm tt. (All have done at the designer only, its worked).

Comment: What's the language of your operating system? Maybe it is working on your PC because it is based on english (?), mine is based on german, that's why I need to change the culture.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same issue. This for the "Why" :
Actually according to MS : https://support2.microsoft.com/Default.aspx?scid=kb%3ben-us%3b889834&x=18&y=19
Date picker don't use the current thread culture : it uses the user regional settings.
SO if you force the date picker custom format something containing "tt", and if the user regional setting doesnt have any designator ... well it won't be shown.

Comment: This is the solution! Setting the current thread culture is not compatible with DateTimePicker. According to the reports and this information, it should work when the thread culture matches the Windows user's region settings though. Stupid design.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
Private Sub mainform_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Timer1.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Label7.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMM dd yyyy  hh:mm:ss tt")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that in Windows settings you also have set time format properly to display AM/PM. Time format in Windows should be also set to H:mm tt to display your result properly.